# Change background of selected button only and keep the background of other buttons same as initial state of buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, select, button

I have a collection view .In collection view ,there are 8 cells ..every cell has a button.On click of a button I have to add a view at its bottom and change its text cor to black from white.To achieve this, i have done the following code

```
-(void)doSomething:(UIButton *) sender {

    if(sender.isSelected){
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:36/255.0 green:71/255.0 blue:113/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    recipeHeading = (RecipeHeadingCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *path = [_headingCollectionView indexPathForCell:recipeHeading];
    UIView *bottomBorder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, sender.frame.size.height + 2.0f, sender.frame.size.width, 30)];
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [sender addSubview:bottomBorder];
    [_outerCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
        sender.selected=false;
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"not selected");
        sender.selected=true;
 }    
}
```

But there is one more scenario to be solved i.e. When you select a button in cell 1 then the rest(even the ones that are earlier selected) should go in unelectable state automatically i.e they should have white title colour and there should be no view at their bottom .
My code works well for the selection thing, but it  doesn't change the state of other unselected buttons.Kindly give me some guidance in this direction .Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to add a model (array of booleans and access it in **cellForRowAtIndexpath**) for every cell that has a true or false value for selection state , and when one cell is clicked refresh the whole table to redraw

```
@interface ViewController ()
```

{

```
   NSMutableArray*allValues;
```

}

in viewDidLoad

```
  allValues = [NSMutableArray new];

  for(int i = 0 ;i<YourTableViewArrayCount;i++)
  {
     [allValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
  }
```

and tableview dataSource

```
  -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

  bool d = [allValues[indexPath.row] boolValue];

  if(d)
  {
      // cell selected
  }
  else
  {
        // cell not selected
  }

  /// implement remaining here

 }
```

**note:** make this array global and change it's values when a cell is clicked in UITableViewCell custom class and reload the **tableView** with **NotificationCenter** or any observer

Comment: Thanks.Can you suggest some code snippet or any link to follow?

Answer (score 0):

When collection view is created provide the button tag as indexPath.item of the cell.
When the button is clicked save the tag of button in a global value(Lets call it **selectedRow** and initially set the value to -1) and reload the collection view.
In cell for item at index if the **selectedRow** and indexPath.item are same show the border and view else hide it.

Hope this helps